# Notepad's .LOG command inside Sublime Text 3

Tags: notepad++, sublime-text-3, notepad, sublime-text

I've been using notepad and notepad++ since forever, but now that i've been coding more I'm using Sublime Text 3. One feature of notepad that I miss most is the .LOG command.

When a file has .LOG on the beginning, every time you open it, it will append the current date and time, it's great for log and journal keeping.

I wonder if there's a similar feature or plugin in sublime text, or how could I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a simple plugin for that, along the lines of the following snippet:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import datetime

class LOGListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):

  def on_load(self, view):
    if view.substr(sublime.Region(0,4)) == ".LOG":
      line = "[%s] " % str(datetime.datetime.now())
      view.run_command( "move_to", {"to": "eof", "extend": False})
      view.run_command("insert", {"characters": line})
```

Another idea is to get the date/time added at the beginning of a line every time you press ENTER. To do that you can define a command and bind it to the ENTER key but to restrict it to LOG files you need to somehow define the corresponding scopes (which can be done).

Comment: actually, the notepad behavior is not triggered when the file ends with the .log extension, but for any text files tha has .LOG written on the first line..

Comment: @raphadko ah that's easily fixed, will edit in a min